# Unable to restore a particular site in FBA configured web application

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I have taken a site backup or export(specific site from site collection e.g http://rootsite1/subsite) http://rootsite1 which is in Windows authentication using `stsadm` Export command. I have successfully restored using `stsadm` Import command in another web application http://rootsite2 which is configured to both authentication windows http://rootsite2intranet) as well FBA(Form Based Authentication,extend the web application(internet facing site) http://rootsite2). But it is working fine in windows authentication but in FBA mode I am unable to view the sub site.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Were you able to successfully access your site with FBA prior to importing your site?

Comment: Yes I can able to access whole site with FBA except the imported site.Any workaround for this issue....

Comment: Can you update your question with any errors or log entries from both windows and ULS?

Answer (score 1):

rootsite2intranet works correctly with windows and FBA?

rootsite2 is extended from rootsite2intranet correct?

When you extend a web application, it will get a new IIS directory.  It will not copy the web.config from the webapp you extended from.  You need to update your web.config file with the same entries from your "working" webapp to support FBA (connectionString, RoleManager,and providers sections).

Comment: roostsite2intranet works fine with both authentications. I have checked the extended web application's web.config file FBA entries are present such as Role manager etc. But still I am unable to access the site.